# PHP Facebook API - post message to the wall with a link to an user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know I cannot post through Facebook API messages to the user's wall with the links which go out of Facebook.

But can I post a message, where would be a link to a Facebook user? So far I didn't find something like that, so trying my luck here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `/me/feed` endpoint you can post to the user's wall, nothing prevents it.

You will need `publish_stream` permission.

```
if ($user) {
        $attachment = array(
            'message' => 'this is my message',
            'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxx',

        );

        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a user who is logged in and authenticated
            $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, BUT: I would need to post the link here: `'message' => 'this is my message',`, for example: `'message' => 'this is my message: <a href="..">LINK</a>',`. I know I can add separated link to the `publish_stream`, but I don't need it.

Comment: @user984621 nothing is stopping you from including a link though you cannot have `<a>` tags and the attachment will not appear. The only way to get the attachment to work is to use `link`

Comment: I am going this way only but gettting error :  Uncaught OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file thrown in E:\wamp\www\Sweepstack\facebookClass\facebook-sdk\base_facebook.php on line 1271

Comment: Instead of having 'message' => 'this is my message' how can you set it to any variable from a $_POST request?
$message = $_POST['content'];
Like 'message' => $message

Answer (score 0):

> I know I cannot post through Facebook API messages to the user's wall
>   with the links which go out of Facebook.

You surely can, using the **feed api**

If the user have given you the permission to publish , you can post any link on his wall.